# Jquery Remove plugin from selected Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

ok i have a table with data in it with a plugin that sorts the table with the text that is in it by clicking on the table header;

i do this with this code

```
$('.sort-table').tablesorter();
```

but if the table is reloaded with AJax i Get Duplicated data then when it is sorted 
is there a way to remove this to then restart it sort of thing .

```
$('.sort-table').tablesorter();
```

Comment: There is no such a general thing like "to remove a plugin". Check the plugin documentation if it can detach itself somehow.